# writing a generic listview template to use across different models

Tags: django

I am new to django and am looking for a generic way of displaying all records of a model in a view by writing minimum html.

So ideally what i would like to do is define my model for example customer, add fields like first name, address, credit card no.
Now i would mark which of these fields are to be rendered ( say publicly_visible = false for credit card field). I repeat this for another model like 'products'.
Next i want my view for customer to render a list of all customer records (the credit card column will not be rendered).

I am wondering if there already is a django package which will do this for me?

The other option which i am trying is to try to use a generic listview to do this but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking for a good solution to generate read-only list views for your models without writing too much code - This did it for me.

https://github.com/miracle2k/django-tables

Answer (score 0):

Meet django's "Class Based Views".

You can read the docs here [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) on CBV, there are several generic views to accomplish repetitve tasks.

The view you're looking for regarding your question is called ListView.